# Django: Access num_pages in view to generate pagination

Tags: django

I want to generate a range of pages in my template when using a `ListView` and it's `pagination`, to generate dynamically the number of pages for the pagination:

[image]

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/

My first attempt was to make a for loop for everyelement in `page_obj.paginator.num_pages`, getting error `int is not iterable`:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
   <ul class="pagination">
    {% for i in page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}
    <li class="page-item">
        <span class="page-link">
          <a href="/catalogo?page={{i}}">
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </span>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul> 
 {% endif }
```

Then I've discovered that there isn't and wont be a range template filter because this calculation should be done in the view and send the range to the template, not generated in the `template`. See:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13088

> So how can I access the `page_obj.paginator.num_pages` inside the
>   view???

**My LisView:**

```
class CatalogoListView(ListView):

    model = UnitaryProduct
    template_name = "shop/catalogo.html"
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        filter_val = self.request.GET.get('filtro', 'todas')
        order = self.request.GET.get('orderby', 'created')
        if filter_val == "todas":
            context = UnitaryProduct.objects.all().filter(available=True).order_by('-created')
            return context
        else:    
            context = UnitaryProduct.objects.filter(
                subcategory2=filter_val,
            ).filter(available=True).order_by('-created')

            return context

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CatalogoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filtro'] = self.request.GET.get('filtro', 'todas')
        context['orderby'] = self.request.GET.get('orderby', 'created')
        context['category'] = Category.objects.get(slug="catalogo")
        return context
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`num_pages` is an integer storing the total number of pages, thus not iterable.

What you are looking for is `page_range`, which is a list of page numbers.
You can iterate on it from your template, just replace

```
{% for i in page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}
```

with

```
{% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
```